# Docker abbreviation for --name run option

Tags: docker

Is there an abbreviated option for `--name`?  For example the following works:

```
docker run -it --name container1 busybox
```

However this does not:

```
docker run -it -n container1 busybox
```

TIA,
Ole

Comment: I think --name is pretty short as it is.

Comment: If you want to simplify it, you can create an alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the short answer, but all arguments are neatly documented here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Excerpt:

```
 -m, --memory=""               Memory limit
 --name=""                     Assign a name to the container
```

As you can see, clearly no shorthand for `--name` defined :)

Comment: You can also see all arguments using `docker run --help` (the same works for all other docker commands as well).

Comment: Thanks - That's what I thought ... But also thought it was odd that something as frequently used as --name does not have an abbreviation.